# I'm having trouble adding two matrices in python

Tags: isa-swizzling

I want to add two matrcies in python 3 but the problem comes when I add `input` to the program

Here is my code

```
def addmatrix(a,b):
    d=[]
    n=0
    while n < len (a):
        c = []
        k = 0
        while k < len (a[0]) : 
            c.append(a[n][k]+b[n][k])
            k += 1 
        n += 1
        d.append (c)
    return d

def main():
    a = input("Enter a Matrix: ")
    b = input("Enter another Matrix: ")
    print (addmatrix(a,b))
main()
```

If the input is

Enter a Matrix: `[[5,6], [1,2], [2,4]]`

Enter another Matrix: `[[2,3], [-6,0], [-2, 4]]`

The output comes out as [['[['], ['[['], ['52'], [',,'], ['63'], [']]'], [',,'], ['  '], ['[['], ['1-'], [',6'], ['2,'], [']0'], [',]'], [' ,'], ['[ '], ['2['], [',-'], ['42'], ['],'], ['] ']]

But if I take out the `input` from the program and make it so that

```
def main():
    a = [[5,6], [1,2], [2,4]]
    b = [[2,3], [-6,0], [-2, 4]]
    print (addmatrix(a,b))
main()
```

The output then comes out as `[[7, 9], [-5, 2], [0, 8]]` which is correct.

Is there a way I can make my program work so that when a person inputs two matrices they add together? I'm new at python so any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: It works fine for me on Python 2.7.3

Comment: I'm using python 3. Maybe thats the problem. Thats anyone know whats wrong?

Comment: @zz3599: OP is using Python 3.

Comment: As an FYI: when working with matrices in python, its best to use [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/), which is designed for fast and easy matrix computation. This looks like it might be homework though, in which case ignore me :)

Comment: @JamesPorter Yeah unfortunately it is. I can't use numpy we haven't learned yet. haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to convert the user input into a Python object. Right now, it's a string.

You can use `eval` (which should **not** be used if you don't know what your users will input. I can type in `__import__('os').system('rm /some/file.txt')` and Python will delete a file):

```
a = eval(input("Enter a Matrix: "))
```

Or you can use `ast.literal_eval`, which is safe:

```
from ast import literal_eval

...

a = literal_eval(input("Enter a Matrix: "))
```

Comment: I don't know what the users will input. It has to be random

Comment: @Jett Then try literal_eval

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import ast

def addmatrix(a,b):
    return [map(sum, zip(*x)) for x in zip(a,b)]

def main():
    a = ast.literal_eval(raw_input("Enter a Matrix: "))
    b = ast.literal_eval(raw_input("Enter another Matrix: "))
    print addmatrix(a,b)

main()
```